# Reading text from table in AutoCAD using python

Tags: python, autocad

I know that pyautocad library can read points in a geometry designed in AutoCAD.
In my case I have tables designed in each Autocad  Dwg file, that I need to find a specific number in them. 
Is this feasible by pyautocad?

Answer (score 1):

pyautocad uses the AutoCAD ActiveX API. You can find in the AutoCAD [ActiveX Reference Guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/FRA/?guid=GUID-5D302758-ED3F-4062-A254-FB57BAB01C44) the available properties and methods for the [Table](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/FRA/?guid=GUID-7B82400C-53D0-4D1A-94FA-66BB3040F0AA) object.

To get the value from a table cell, simply use the [GetCellValue method](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/FRA/?guid=GUID-AD64910D-2FFF-419E-9C96-9FF9BE48CFBC).

```
table.GetCellValue(row_index, column_index)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please give me some hints how to get the value from a table cell ?